# Correct os.pipe usage in Windows with multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pipe, python-multiprocessing

The problem is: `os.pipe()` seems does not work in Windows when the read-end and writ-end are in different processes.

```py
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(pin):
    print('func.pin:', pin)
    b = os.read(pin, 4096)
    print('func.1: b =', b)
    b = os.read(pin, 4096)
    print('func.2: b =', b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pin, pout = os.pipe()
    print('main.pin:', pin, ' pout:', pout)

    os.write(pout, b'abc123')

    #b = os.read(pin, 4096)
    #print('main.1: b =', b)  # will work as intended

    pfunc = mp.Process(target = func, args=(pin,))
    pfunc.start()
    pfunc.join()
```

Expected output (blocked second read):

```
main.pin: 3  pout: 4
func.pin: 3
func.1: b = b'abc123'
```

Observed output:

```
main.pin: 3  pout: 4
func.pin: 3
func.1: b = b''
func.2: b = b''
```

i.e. Windows neither read correctly from the pipe nor block the read operation. Although the file ID is correct.

My questions are:

1. Why I cannot operate the pipe as intended (like in Linux, the expected output)?
2. How to modify it to make it work?

I know `multiprocessing.Pipe`, but I want to use something simpler (potentially faster) like `os.pipe`, because all I need is just a byte stream pipe.

I have done some search and found these: [os.pipe creates inheritable FDs with a bad internal state on Windows](https://bugs.python.org/issue32865), [Passing pipes to subprocesses in Python in Windows](https://www.digitalenginesoftware.com/blog/archives/47-Passing-pipes-to-subprocesses-in-Python-in-Windows.html). I cannot fully understand them, it sounds to me that `os.pipe` is not well supported in this circumstance, particularly the subprocess can not access pipe easily (or even not possible?).

Background: I'm learning some network programming in Python, and writing a program that separate network streaming and data processing in different processes by multiprocessing module.

Comment: The multiprocessing module doesn't create child processes with inheritance enabled, so it doesn't matter that the underlying pipe handle is or is not inheritable. Instead, the multiprocessing module manually duplicates handles to the child. This is already implemented for you by the provided IPC types, such as [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe). This is just a named pipe, not any different in performance from the anonymous pipe you get from `os.pipe`.

Comment: Can't believe that I got an answer from the developer in a link I just refereed. ...ahem, so, I think you almost answered my question, showing why and clarifying the official solution. I will buy it if you write it as an answer... just curious, is this compatibility problem between `os.pipe` and `multiprocessing` Windows only? Is this intended by design?

Comment: I'm just a long-time user of Python who knows a thing or two about Windows, so I contribute back by helping to triage and diagnose Windows issues.

Comment: Yes, it is intentional that the ["spawn"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) start method does not inherit Windows handles or Unix file descriptors from the parent process, regardless of the platform. Windows only supports "spawn", whereas Unix platforms support and default to the "fork" start method. The middle ground is the "forkserver" start method, which is safe for use by a multithreaded Unix process.